# Dialogflow sign in user payload

Tags: google-signin, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, user-data

I have implemented Account linking with Google Sign-In into dialogflow but I can't retrieve the user datas. 
Into my webhook "actions_intent_SIGN_IN", conv.user.profile.payload is always empty.

However signing in seems to have worked as SIGN_IN status is "OK".

Here is the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in

Here is my fulfillment webhook:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {WebhookClient, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {dialogflow, Permission, Image, SignIn, BasicCard} = require('actions-on-google');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});

const {ssml} = require('./util');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({request, response});
    let conv = agent.conv();

    function ask_for_sign_in(agent) {
        let conv = agent.conv();
        conv.ask(new SignIn('Per personalizzare'));
        agent.add(conv);
    }

    function actions_intent_SIGN_IN(agent) {

        let conv = agent.conv();

        const granted = conv.arguments.get('SIGN_IN').status === 'OK';

        console.log('name', conv.user.profile.payload);

        if(granted){
            agent.add('granted');
        }else{
            agent.add('not granted');
        }

        agent.add('test');
    }

    // Map from Dialogflow intent names to functions to be run when the intent is matched
    let intentMap = new Map();

    intentMap.set('ask_for_sign_in', ask_for_sign_in);
    intentMap.set('actions_intent_SIGN_IN', actions_intent_SIGN_IN);

    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

conv.user.profile.payload is only populated if you use "actions-on-google" library. since you are using "dialogflow-fulfillment" as your webhook client, you have to do the token verification yourself. you can access the JWT token from conv.request.user.idToken

here is document explaining how to do the verification 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth